# Function that shows all lists, which are ascending

Tags: haskell

I have to write a function, that check which lists of list are ascending and show them in list.
This is what I wrote, but it says "Non-exhaustive patterns in function f3"

```
f :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
f [] = []
f [x:xs] =
 if helper (x:xs) == True 
     then (x:xs) : f [xs]
     else f [xs]


helper :: [Int] -> Bool
helper [] = True
helper [x] = True
helper (x:y:xs) = x <= y && helper (y:xs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces an error because `[x:xs]` will only match with a *singleton* list (a list with *exactly* one element), and that single item is a non-empty list.

You however do not need to match the inner list, you can filter with:

```
f :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
f [] = []
f (x:xs)
    | helper x = x : f xs
    | otherwise = f xs
```

which is a [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) function:

```
f :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
f = filter helper
```

You can further generalize this to work with a list of lists of items that are a member of the `Ord` typeclass:

```
helper :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
helper [] = True
helper xa@(_:xs) = and (zipWith (<=) xa xs)
```

or as [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118735/function-that-shows-all-lists-which-are-ascending/62118793?noredirect=1#comment109869656_62118793):

```
helper :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
helper xs = and (zipWith (>=) xs (drop 1 xs))
```

and then we can filter with the generalized `helper`:

```
f :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
f = filter helper
```

Comment: Just for fun: your last `helper` can also be coalesced into a single line, which feels nice to me: `helper xs = and (zipWith (<=) (drop 1 xs) xs)`.

Comment: `f = filter $ and . (zipWith (<=) <*> drop 1)`